# Why does excel rowcount return max row, after a change on the sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

The code works "beautifully"(it needs to be cleaned up etc.) but if I delete rows or modify rows in `Worksheets("Material For Quotation")` and rerun the code it defaults to the max rowcount (1,048,576). I've searched around and read the Microsoft stuff and I cant figure it out. What I am stumped on is that the code should run independent of what's in the worksheet, but the minute I delete or modify the worksheet rowcount doesn't work.

Does anyone have insight?

```
Sub QuoteToMaterial()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws, wscheck, ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

Dim i, j, k, l As Integer
Dim dict As New Dictionary
Dim Str As String

Dim key As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Material For Quotation")
i = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
j = 1
'init dictionary
For j = 2 To i
    If dict.Exists(Trim(UCase(ws1.Cells(j, 3).value))) = True Then
        dict(Trim(UCase(ws1.Cells(j, 3).value))) = dict(Trim(UCase(ws1.Cells(j, 3).value))) + ws1.Cells(j, 4).value
    Else
        dict.Add ws1.Cells(j, 3).value, ws1.Cells(j, 4).value
    End If
    
Next j

i = wb.Worksheets.Count
j = 1

For k = 1 To i
    Set wscheck = wb.Worksheets(k)
    Select Case True
        Case wscheck.Name = "Summary"
            GoTo Loopiter 'loop iterate
        Case wscheck.Name = "Material For Quotation"
            GoTo Loopiter
        Case wscheck.Name = "Pricing Summary"
            GoTo Loopiter
        Case wscheck.Name = "Installation 1"
            GoTo Loopiter
        Case wscheck.Name = "Installation 2"
            GoTo Loopiter
        Case wscheck.Name = "Inst Worksheet 1"
            GoTo Loopiter
        Case wscheck.Name = "Inst Worksheet 2"
            GoTo Loopiter
        Case Else
           
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(k)
        'inserts $ per unit into the right place
        For l = 4 To 101
            
            If dict.Exists(ws.Cells(l, 9).value) = True Then
                ws.Cells(l, 11).value = dict(ws.Cells(l, 9).value)
            End If
            
        Next l

        j = j + 1
     End Select
Loopiter:
Next k

    

End Sub
```

Comment: And by that you meant that `i` is set to that count? Sidenodes though: just something I found that looks "wrong" is: `dict(Trim(UCase(ws1.Cells(j, 3).value))) = dict(Trim(UCase(ws1.Cells(j, 3).value))`. Did you mean to add `cells(j,4)` instead? Another small note is that you can rewrite your `Select Case` a whole lot shorter. Also, the way you dim your variables.....you'll find you are using a lot of default appointed variables since you effectively not dimming these the same.

Comment: Not likely that `i` is greater than 32,767 since you declared it as Integer.  Should be `Long`.  So, not sure what is resetting to max row count.

Comment: @DarrellH, as per my previous comment, `i` is actually **not** declared as Integer, but however as `Variant/Empty` on declaration. Valid point on the `Long` type though =)

Comment: @JvdV, you are correct, if he would have been successful at dimming them he would have had the problem of `Integer` vs `Long`.

Comment: It's not clear, how and when the row count "defaults" to 1,048,576 the max number of rows, when `i` is calculated only once at the begining `i = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`. Could you please elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys the answer to this problem is that we ending up putting table formatting on columns 1-4 down to row 1,048,576. So using `ws.cells(rows.count,2)` goes to the bottom because they are all taken up by a table.

to correct either remove the table formatting and just cell fill to get the look or use the `listobject` and get the number of filled rows there.

[Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Sorry all I didn't realize the problem until everyone focused on the messy code lol

Thx.